# String or binary data of '' would be truncated

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to resize a column down to 64 characters in length:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[consumption]
ALTER COLUMN [resourceGroup] VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL
```

but I get the following error:

> String or binary data would be truncated in table 'dbo.consumption', column 'resourceGroup'. Truncated value: ''.

This doesn't make sense to me: how can you truncate nothing?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @DaleK I did that and, yes, I see data longer than 64 characters. My question is more as to why the error message doesn't show the actual string that violated the column and why I get an empty string as this is misleading.

Comment: Does just look like a quirk of `ALTER TABLE` https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKsC1.png that it uses the extended error message but without the offending value

Comment: @DaleK No, this column is populated from data that cannot contain whitespace characters.

Comment: @MartinSmith That makes sense. It just threw me for a loop because the data source I'm working from "guarantees" that the data going into this column won't be longer than 64 characters so I assumed that SQL server was doing something weird rather than assuming that the data source was providing data that violated its own contract.

Comment: The extended error message with details of the value is somewhat recent so I'm assuming that they didn't implement it in this code path (possibly as knowing just one arbitrary value that fails out of potentially many is unlikely to be that useful in this context)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to comments by @MartinSmith and @DaleK, I think I've come to the answer on this one.

The documentation provided with the data source I'm writing to this column stated that it should not be longer than 64 characters. Then, when I tried changing the length of the column, the error message led me to believe that SQL Server was issuing an error over an empty string. According to @MartinSmith, this type of error message is a recent development and so the offending value probably hasn't been injected into it yet for `ALTER TABLE` commands. Moreover, queries against the column reveal that it does contain values longer than 64 characters.

Therefore, this error message should be taken at its meaning and the truncation value ignored.

Comment: @TomTom I did not assume there was only one string that caused the command to fail. My assumption was that, since there were quotes included in the error message, then there would be something inside those quotes. If the error message had not included the quotes then I would not have made any assumptions about the data at all but because they were there, I was naturally inclined to use that information.